# Python Execute Shell commands without having a terminal open

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess, gnome-shell

I'm writing a script that should focus a given application if its already running otherwise launch the application.

I'm using the `run()` method of the `subprocess` module to run a few shell commands to check whether an instance is currently running and if not to start a new one.

The script works perfectly fine if executed from a terminal, however isn't doing anything if launched via a keyboard shortcut from Gnome Shell.

My Question is how do I execute the shell commands without having a terminal open?

Here is a snippet of the code I use to the the shell commands:

```
def focus_instance_of(application):
    # Moves the window to the current desktop, raises it und gives it focus
    print("Put " + application + " in focus...")
    subprocess.run(["wmctrl", "-R", application])
```

Comment: Try the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* how you execute commands (no shell necessary) "without having a terminal open".

If it executes correctly from a terminal - command line, I assume - and not from the Gnome Shell, then some feature of the different environment is likely causing it to fail.

I suggest you redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file so you can start to debug this. Check for unhandled exceptions. Also check the output and return code of the `wmctrl` execution, it may be reporting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the keyword argument `shell=True`, this will spawn a shell in the background to run the command (but not open the terminal window).

```
subprocess.run(["wmctrl", "-R", application], shell=True)
```

Comment: The fact that the script is working correctly when launched from the CLI suggests the problem is not the absence of a shell. Moreover, there's no reason why `wmctrl` would require a shell.